# Issue when calculating the partition function for a spring

Tags: thermodynamics, partition-function

I have a question where I need to write down the partition function of a classical spring with $E = \frac{1}{2}kx^2$. The goal is to show thermodynamically that the force is $-kx$.

From $U = -\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta } \ln(Z)$ it is clear that: $$Z = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\beta kx^2}$$

From here the required result is easy to get to.

However if I try evaluate $Z$ by summing over all states I obtain something completely different:

$$Z \propto \int{e^{-\beta E(x)}}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^{-\beta \frac{1}{2}kx^2}}dx = \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{k\beta}}$$

Why do these 2 methods produce totally different answers? I feel like I must have some fundamental misunderstanding but I don't see what it could be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first expression depends on $x$, which is the parameter of a microstate. But $U$ is the average energy of an ensemble of microstates and does not include an undetermined variable $x$. Your second expression is right.

Indeed, if you calculate $U = -\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \ln Z$ from your second definition, you find $U = \frac{1}{2} k_B T$. Thus, you have effectively derived the [equipartition theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem).